# Unexpected behavior in for loop

Tags: python, csv, xlrd

**Preface:**
 I'm a student worker who was asked to update a script that pulls data from and an excel book and arrange it to meet a predefined format. It seems to me that there is a problem in my inner for loop. It gets stuck on the first row and never progresses to the next row.

**Loop in question:**

```
alt3_sheet = book.sheet_by_name("alt3_specific")
for row in range(3, 729 ):
    #if uniqueID not in alt3_specific:
    temp = []
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 12).value)     # access
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 13).value)     # catch
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 14).value)     # CPUE
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 15).value)     # anglerdays
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 16).value)     # visits
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 17).value)     # sheeppue
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 18).value)     # moosepue
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 19).value)     # cariboupue
    temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 20).value)     # king
    alt3_specific[uniqueID] = temp
```

**The whole script:**

```
import xlrd
import csv

book = xlrd.open_workbook("Data_for_Kyle_6_clogit_4.xlsx")

def distance_key(start, end):
    return str(start) + "-" + str(end)

#Load IDs
id_crosswalk = book.sheet_by_name("crosswalk for ID")
id_lookup = {}
for row in range(1, id_crosswalk.nrows):
    id_lookup[id_crosswalk.cell(row, 0).value] = id_crosswalk.cell(row, 1).value

#Load alt3
alt3_crosswalk = book.sheet_by_name("crosswalk for alt3")
alt3_lookup = {}
for row in range(1, alt3_crosswalk.nrows):
    alt3_lookup[alt3_crosswalk.cell(row, 0).value] = alt3_crosswalk.cell(row, 2).value

distances_sheet = book.sheet_by_name("distances")
distances_lookup = {}
for row in range(1, distances_sheet.nrows):
    distances_lookup[distance_key(distances_sheet.cell(row, 2).value, distances_sheet.cell(row, 1).value)] = distances_sheet.cell(row, 4).value 

DATA_sheet = book.sheet_by_name("DATA")
alt3_specific = {}
id_alt3_specific = {}

for row in range(1, DATA_sheet.nrows):
    sampleID = DATA_sheet.cell(row, 5).value # SampleID

    # Load alt3 specific data
    uniqueID = DATA_sheet.cell(row, 50).value # UniqueIDnew
    alt3_sheet = book.sheet_by_name("alt3_specific")
    for row in range(3, 729 ):
        #if uniqueID not in alt3_specific:
        temp = []
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 12).value)     # access
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 13).value)     # catch
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 14).value)     # CPUE
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 15).value)     # anglerdays
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 16).value)     # visits
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 17).value)     # sheeppue
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 18).value)     # moosepue
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 19).value)     # cariboupue
        temp.append(alt3_sheet.cell(row, 20).value)     # king
        alt3_specific[uniqueID] = temp

    #load alt3 + id specific
    id_w_alt3 = str(sampleID) + "-" + str(uniqueID)
    temp = []
    temp.append(distances_lookup[distance_key(DATA_sheet.cell(row, 115).value, DATA_sheet.cell(row, 116).value)])   # distance_k
    temp.append(DATA_sheet.cell(row,10).value)  # AnnualFl
    temp.append(DATA_sheet.cell(row, 13).value) # ContFlight
    temp.append(DATA_sheet.cell(row, 57).value) # DestStay
    id_alt3_specific[id_w_alt3] = temp

# This pull all the socio data from the SOC sheet.
soc = book.sheet_by_name("SOC")
soc_lookup = {}
for row in range(4, soc.nrows):
    sampleID = soc.cell(row, 0).value
    data = []
    for col in range(2, 39):
        data.append(soc.cell(row, col).value)
    soc_lookup[sampleID] = data

f = open("output_clogit.csv", "w")
out_csv = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
header = ["ID", "alt3", "access", "catch", "CPUE", "anglerdays", "visits",
    "sheeppue", "moosepue", "cariboupue", "king", "choice", "distance_k",
    "AnnualFl",  "ContFlight", "DestStay", "City", "AncMatSu", "Kenai", "Kodiak",
    "Fairbanks", "Urban", "Rural",  "Source", "Income", "Confidence",
    "Pax", "StartHUC", "wave", "flights", "flightsw", "wgt1", "ContFlights", 
    "ContFlightsw", "wgtC", "Eflights", "Eflightsw", "wgtE", "age",
    "pweight", "SetUniqueDest", "REVspfish", "REVview", "REVhunt", "REVother", 
    "REVdev", "REVcabn", "StartID","StartElodea", "maxlegkm", "plntype",
    "kmcost", "kmrev"]

out_csv.writerow(header)

sorted_ids = sorted(id_lookup.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v)
sorted_alt3 = sorted(alt3_lookup.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v)

for (key, value) in sorted_ids:
    for (alt3_key, alt3) in sorted_alt3:
        # ID and Alt3
        output = [value, alt3]

        # Load data that is consistent for Alt 3
        output += alt3_specific[alt3_key]

        id_alt3_key = str(key) + '-' + str(alt3_key)
        # Load data that is specific to ID and Alt 3 IF IT EXISTS
        if id_alt3_key in id_alt3_specific:
            output += ["1"]
            output += id_alt3_specific[id_alt3_key]
        else:
            output += ["0"]
            output += distances_lookup[(id_alt3_specific[id_alt3_key[0]])]
            output += ["0","0","0"]

        # Load SOC data
        output += soc_lookup[key]

        out_csv.writerow(output)

f.close()
```

Any help is appreciated I've been staring at this for hours I'm sure the bug is obvious but I can see it.

Comment: How do you know it's stuck rather than just taking a long time?

Comment: How big is the file your reading?

Comment: Both your inner and outer loop use `row` as a loop variable. Change the inner loop to use a different name (perhaps `inner_row`).

Comment: @cricket_007 I added a counter in both loops along with some print statements. Its counting up but it is getting the same row of data. This was confirmed when I printed row's value and saw 3 727 times.